# Fixed position and translateZ in Chrome cuts of a part of my content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a multicolumn page. Left panel (red bar in the example) has a fixed position  and a static size. And it should also be scrollable when there are a lot of content in it.

In this column there might be a popover over some content (in the example it is blue). Popover also has a fixed position, it should be visible over the entire page and not only inside the red bar.

As a result in Chrome popover is visible only within the red bar when I have property transform: translateZ(0) applied either to popover itself or to any child node in this popover. My example is simplified, in real case - I have a scroll plugin that does apply that property to some child node.

I have checked in Firefox - everything is OK there.

Is there any workarounds to solve this issue in Chrome as well?

```css
.left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
}
.popover {
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel ornare nunc. Proin ultrices enim erat, hendrerit tempus erat congue nec. Curabitur malesuada massa dolor. Aenean sit amet erat quis tortor egestas fringilla. Phasellus venenatis augue
  et mi accumsan, sit amet mollis nisi ullamcorper. Etiam eget dignissim augue, nec elementum elit. Proin elementum neque at consequat convallis. Praesent eu fringilla diam. Suspendisse efficitur ornare sapien. Praesent hendrerit arcu purus, eget imperdiet
  tortor luctus sit amet. Donec tempor orci neque, eget commodo erat dictum iaculis. Nullam commodo egestas mauris. In auctor quam vitae ligula accumsan, sit amet tempus ligula sollicitudin. Maecenas eget enim ac sapien cursus pretium ac in mauris. Praesent
  faucibus ullamcorper elit nec convallis. Phasellus metus nulla, gravida id sapien convallis, porta sagittis nisl. Morbi lacinia augue sit amet mi viverra, sit amet blandit purus sagittis. Donec placerat lacus purus, id luctus nisl dapibus sed. Vivamus
  feugiat sit amet neque quis condimentum. In vel odio orci. Phasellus ultricies ex ligula, et tempus lorem finibus at. Vivamus nec tempor ante. Sed et rhoncus diam. Fusce consectetur, augue vel interdum viverra, odio felis cursus orci, at bibendum enim
  urna suscipit nisi. Nunc sit amet ex nisi. Maecenas sit amet enim eget ipsum sagittis tempor. Curabitur rutrum turpis eget sapien convallis, et pharetra ligula tempor. Vivamus purus mi, tincidunt a dapibus id, vestibulum quis est. Ut lacinia ex rutrum,
  euismod ante eget, gravida ex. Maecenas fermentum ligula sit amet nisl viverra ullamcorper. Proin tincidunt fermentum dui ac gravida. Phasellus molestie, purus vitae elementum lacinia, lacus velit dapibus augue, in viverra arcu lacus nec massa. Praesent
  nec quam in nisl posuere tempus sed at tortor. Proin efficitur vehicula lacus, at aliquet massa varius quis. Mauris sed purus eget elit molestie laoreet tempor nec orci. Suspendisse ipsum dolor, tristique nec magna euismod, blandit ullamcorper mauris.
  Aliquam in tincidunt mauris. Vestibulum ante lorem, consequat sit amet purus id, tincidunt fermentum eros. Donec ultricies leo quis sapien aliquet, ut imperdiet enim cursus. Fusce commodo ac arcu quis facilisis. Proin dignissim pulvinar pretium. Mauris
  vel libero turpis. Integer eu viverra nisl, vel rhoncus augue. Suspendisse et iaculis nisi. Sed nec ipsum neque. Nam quis metus eget velit suscipit suscipit. Quisque est metus, maximus ut dui eget, auctor convallis nibh. Praesent congue ipsum eget tellus
  tincidunt, eget tempor urna vulputate. Quisque erat nulla, tincidunt ac scelerisque eu, posuere eget risus. Ut feugiat id nisi sit amet pharetra. Nam at elit eget lacus scelerisque efficitur. Sed vel lacus sed dui condimentum pulvinar in a tortor. Duis
  in ex eu orci condimentum varius in rutrum tellus. Quisque neque ipsum, fringilla venenatis nisl in, iaculis venenatis nisl. Nullam augue tortor, venenatis vel magna id, rutrum egestas ante. Vestibulum nec tincidunt sapien.

  <div class="popover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you move it outside the `<div class="left">`?

Comment: @Sprazer This is a simplified example, in my real case there a lot of nesting and that popover is a part of viewmodel of another viewmodel of viewmodel of sidebar - so it is not that easy